# Change a URL in HREF with Screen Resolution as test

Tags: javascript, html, css

Need help with what will hopefully need to be a JavaScript to handle a test/result code.  First, I am NOT a programmer and am completely lost so I would need all coding if you can.

My dilemma is that I'm building a subdomain (ie: subname.mainsite.com) and using it to test Bootstrap - combination CSS/JavaScript system to make pages change the layout dynamically depending on the screen resolution. Use one page for all devices (PC, tablet, mobile).

However, I need the subdomain hypertext links go to an Ecommerce site that still uses separate pages for mobile and computer screen resolutions so ONE link will have to have TWO URLs to go to depending on the screen resolution that the page is in at the time it's clicked on.

Since it will be multiple links on the page with ever-changing page links, is there a JavaScript code I can put in the "Head" tag of the page so that when I make a Hypertext link on the page, I can have it do a test at that point in the page such as: "if screen resolution is 786px or smaller, use [this URL], else (for larger screens/non-mobile sized) use [THIS URL Instead]"

I'm trying to avoid building a database of links since it will be ever-changing depending on the content and where that content is on the page.  I have a combination of text and HTML buttons that I have on the page and they use the traditional "a href=" tags for links.  Hope this is enough of an explanation for someone to help.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery? And can you provide sample url's, just for testing / demo sake?

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple, here's an example.

```
<a id="myLink" href="http://highresolutionurl">My Link</a>
```

with this bit of javaScript:

```
<script>
if (screen.width < 768) {
    document.getElementById('myLink').setAttribute('href', "http://lowresolutionurl");
}
</script>
```

I think the code is readable even for a non-programmer to understand.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is quite simple. You should investigate more before posting this type of questions. In Stackoverflow we do not make work for others, we help solve.

The code I wrote is a general example, the way you want this for you to work better is the second answer to this post.

```
<script>
    var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName('anchors-that-redirect-to-resolution-website'); // Example, it could even be anchor tags as well.
    var screen_resolution = window.innerWidth;

    for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {             
        anchors[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            if(screen_resolution < 768){
                window.location = "your_desired_custom_url";
            } else {
                window.location = "your_desired_custom_url";
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Someone gave me a very simplistic version of this:

'<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 780) {
    window.location = "http://www.endoscopy.com/mobile/service.asp";
  } 
  else { 
   window.location = "http://www.endoscopy.com/service";
  }
  //-->
</script>'

Comment: I put it in the '<head>' tag to auto-load with the page I reference.